# VBA - UDF handles Arrays differently

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, vba

This code is a small subset of what I am working on. I have narrowed the problem down to the following piece. I have this UDF SampleFunction, to which I need to pass an Array, {3;4} as the sole argument.

```
Function SampleFunction(InputVar As Variant) As Integer
    SampleFunction = InputVar(LBound(InputVar))
End Function
```

I call this UDF in two different ways. First, through VBA

### Case 1:

```
Sub testSF()
    MsgBox SampleFunction(Array(3, 4))
End Sub
```

And secondly, through my excel worksheet as

### Case 2:

`={SampleFunction(ROW(3:4))}` -> i.e. as an array function.

### The Problem:

The UDF works for Case 1, i.e. the call through VBA, it gives a `#VALUE` error for Case 2, when I call it through the excel worksheet.

I stepped through the function using F8 for Case 2. `Lbound(InputVar)` evaluates to 1 (which is different from calling from the sub in Case 1, there it evaluates to 0), yet `InputVar(Lbound(InputVar))` shows the "Subscript out of Range" error in Case 2.

All I want to know is **how to call SampleFunction function from a worksheet**, i.e. Case 2 so that it has the same behaviour as Case 1 shown above. As a bonus, it would be nice if someone could explain why `Lbound(InputVar)` evaluates differently in the above cases.

**Some Other Details:**

I am building a UDF to perform some regex manipulations. The argument `InputVar` above, will be an array {x;y;z;...} specifying the xth, yth, zth ... occurences. The data type of `InputVar` is kept to Variant because I want to be able to pass either numbers (as a one length array), arrays, or ranges (taken in and converted to array) to the function.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you have two problems. First, I don't think your code will evaluate if you use `SampleFunction` in a non-array formula, i.e., if InputVar is a Range. You need to incorporate some way of dealing with different types of input that can be passed into the variant. Second, your code assumes the InputVar is a one-dimensional array. This will lead to an error for any multi-dimensional array. This is the source of the `'Subscript out of range.'` error, because array functions pass all array arguments as two-dimensional arrays even if they are can be represented as one-dimensional.

I would suggest declaring a new dynamic array in your function and then setting it equal to InputVar. In the past I've made this work for array and non-array formulas with something like below. Also, note the change to how the first item from the array is retrieved.

```
Option Explicit
Function SampleFunc(InputVar As Variant) As Integer

Dim tmpArray() As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
tmpArray = InputVar

'Added extra argument to LBound since dynamic arrays have two dimensions by default.
SampleFunc = tmpArray(LBound(tmpArray, 1), LBound(tmpArray, 2))
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
'Handles the case where InputVar is a Range.
tmpArray = InputVar.Value
Resume Next

End Function
```

This is quick and dirty, esp. the error handling, but hopefully the basic idea is helpful.

Comment: Looking back at this, I think you can leave the `LBound()` calls out all together and use this instead: `SampleFunc = tmpArray(1, 1)`

Comment: Thank you. That was unbelievably helpful. Would've never thought that the difference was in dimensions :). Also, I have already handled the Range possibility for InputVar explicitly using `IsObject` and `TypeOf InputVar is Excel.Range', so that bit seems to be working (for now :)). Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect.  That's much better than the error handler I have above.  I'm glad this helped!

Comment: @Excelll: LBound is better, since it will work with 0 based arrays as well.